# Delete an ECS stack using Cloudformation yaml code

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS service which is created from a CloudFormation yaml code.
Now, i want to delete it, so simply i removed the code block which contained the creation of this stack from the yaml.
But while deploying that code, the AWS console says that the ECS can't be deleted while the services are active ??

Shouldn't the AWS / CloudFormation take care of making the tasks zero and then delete it ??

If not, what is the workaround here ?